# Create a euphonious word

Tags: kotlin

All the letters of the English alphabet are divided into vowels and consonants.

A word is considered euphonious if it doesn't have three or more vowels or consonants in a row.

My goal is to create euphonious words from the discordant ones and output the minimum number of characters needed to create a euphonious word from a given word.

**Examples:**

**Input:**
schedule
**Output:**
1

**Input:**
biiiiig
**Output:**
2

**Code**

```
fun main() {
    val word = readLine()!!.toMutableList()
    checkWord(word)
}

fun isVowel(c: Char): Boolean {
    val vowels = listOf('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y')
    return c in vowels
}

fun checkWord(word: MutableList<Char>){
    var counter = 0
    for (number in 0 .. word.size - 2) {
        if (isVowel(word[number]) && isVowel(word[number + 1]) && isVowel(word[number + 2])) {
            counter++
            word.add(number + 2, 'b')
//            println(word)
        }
        if (!isVowel(word[number]) && !isVowel(word[number + 1]) && !isVowel(word[number + 2])) {
            counter++
            word.add(number + 2, 'a')
//            println(word)
        }
    }
    println(counter)
}
```

My code is working for those examples but not for a case like *eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee* where the output is supposed to be 8 but my counter is 6.

Comment: word length is increasing but your for loop is not extended. use a while instead.

Comment: @MohammadOmidvar Ty very much

Comment: @BrownieBrown did the answers help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the list is growing as you iterate, your for loop never reaches the end of the list. Your code can be fixed by replacing

```
for (number in 0 .. word.size - 2) {
```

with

```
var number = -1
while (++number < word.size - 1) {
```

so it checks the current list size on each iteration.

I want to point out however that it is unnecessary to use a MutableList and keep enlarging it since you don't use the "fixed" euphonious list afterwards. It is also unnecessary to repeatedly search neighbors on each iteration. You can just count as you go.

```
fun checkWord (word: String) {
    var count = 0
    var currentTypeCount = 0
    var lastTypeVowel = true
    for (c in word) {
        if (isVowel(c) == lastTypeVowel) {
            if (++currentTypeCount == 3) {
                count++
                currentTypeCount = 1
            }
        } else {
            lastTypeVowel = !lastTypeVowel
            currentTypeCount = 1
        }
    }
    println(count)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's analyze the modifications of your word:

- eebeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
- eebeebeeeeeeeeeeeee
- eebeebeebeeeeeeeeeee
- eebeebeebeebeeeeeeeee
- eebeebeebeebeebeeeeeee
- eebeebeebeebeebeebeeeee
- eebeebeebeebeebeebeebeee
- eebeebeebeebeebeebeebeebe

Your last 2 modification take place on the letters with index, which is bigger than your word's original length. That happens because `for` loop iterations number is dependent on your word's original length.
I recommend you to use `while` loop, as its condition is always recalculated and `word.size` will be updated there

```
var i = 0
while (i + 2 < word.size) {
    // the same logic
    i++
}
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining in detail. That helped me a lot.

Comment: `while` goes before the parentheses. `i` should only be incremented by one to use the same logic.